# Highcharts line not plotting

Tags: mysql, highcharts

I have used an example and can successfully read data using php and mysql and plot it (timebase vs a variable), all works fine.  I have taken that and used it as a template and used a different db that doesn't use a timebase but the graph isn't rendering.  The graph is meant to display data from an SQL query that collates the frequency of occurrence of a variable with the variable on the x axis and the frequency of occurrence on the Y axis.

The chart pops up with the x and y axis values as expected.  It looks right; except the plot is missing.  To assist my troubleshooting I have listed the data on the screen albeit not pretty- this proves the db is being called correctly and there are no obvious SQL errors and that data is being returned.

db_code`

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","hal9000");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("sqm", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT magnitude, COUNT(*) AS xxx FROM data WHERE magnitude > 1 GROUP by magnitude");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['magnitude'] . "\t" . $row['xxx']. "\n";
}

mysql_close($con);
?> `
```

main_page code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'common_LHS',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Magnitude',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: true,
                                symbol: 'circle',
                                radius: 0
                             }
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'linear',
                        tickWidth: 0,
                        gridLineWidth: 1,
                        labels: {
                            align: 'center',
                            x: -3,
                            y: 20
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Frequency of occurrence'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 100,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        crosshairs: [{
                            width: 2,
                            color: 'red'
                        }, {
                            width: 2,
                            color: 'red'
                        }],
                   },

                    series: [{
                        name: 'Occurrence',
                    }]
                }

                jQuery.get('data.php', null, function(tsv) {
                    var lines = [];
                    traffic = [];
                    try {
                        // split the data return into lines and parse them
                        tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                        jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                            line = line.split(/\t/);
                            traffic.push ([
                                parseFloat(line[0]),        //need to parseFloat to convert data to float from string
                                parseFloat(line[1])
                            ]);
                        });
                    } catch (e) {  }
                    options.series[0].data = traffic;
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            });
```

The data looks as I expected when graphed in LibreCalc, apart from the line not rendering it is almost done in Highcharts.

Appreciate any advice.  Unfortunately since I am new to this forum I can't submit images but happy to send them to someone if it helps.

Expect it is something simple, usually is :)

Comment: Does `traffic` contain items? Try in your `options.series[0]` definition to also set `data: []` where you set `name: 'Occurance'`.

Comment: Is your data correctly sorted ? I mean, `traffic` is built in an ascending order regarding `line[0]` ?

Comment: The data is sorted via the MySQL, there are 1557 unique points to plot however my datetime graph that works has 18000 so this isn't working very hard.

I am new to this so appreciate your input. I assume you meant
series: [{
   name: 'Occurrence',
   data: [ ]
]}

If so it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the way you build your `traffic` array. It might not be well sorted. Try to sort it by the first element, using something like:

```
function Comparator(a,b){
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
    if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
    return 0;
}

traffic.sort(Comparator);

options.series[0].data = traffic;
```

Does it give you a different result ? Also, does your browser console log something when rendering the chart ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I said it would be simple and it was.

I added ,10 to make sure it was decimal and it didn't make any difference.  I changed it to 16 and was expecting the values to change and it did so it was definitely reading the data although it still didn't plot the data.

I then added .replace(',', '') to the y axis and it worked.

parseFloat  (line[1],10),
parseFloat  (line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)

Seems it doesn't like comma's in the data value!